# asp.net calendar control: is it good?

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking to determine if I'm going to use the calendar control that's out-of-the-box in ASP.NET 4 or if I should look elsewhere, may be a jQuery calendar that just receives json or another .net server option.

Has anyone worked with the native calendar control?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it to be used as a date picker or to display events?

Comment: Say what you want to do with it and we can say if this would work with the ASP.Net-Calendar(btw, its there since 1.1).

Comment: @IrishChieftain: it'll be used for both. In the case where it's used to display events, it'll be used for reporting (ie on dates, it'll show: x apples - y oranges - z fruits)

Comment: My advice would be to use a DataList to render a list of the events and use a simpler datepicker calendar to select the dates. The Calendar control is notoriously difficult when it comes to messing up a page layout for displaying (stretching table cells)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally do not like asp.net native calendar control due to lack of extensibility. I would create a JQuery control since it will be more responsive(client-side). 
Or take a look here: http://www.eworldui.net/

Answer (score 1):

I personally like Rick Strahl's implementation of the [link text][jQuery Date Picker]  for ASP.Net.   I used the one at http://www.eworldui.net/ prior to discovering the West Wind date picker, and will never go back.